# Declaration of Volatile Pointer Array in C++

Tags: c++, xcode, atomic-swap

I have  a struct called Ambigous, and inside the struct I have an array of pointers to other Ambigous.

I want to use OSAtomic.h library, to do CompareandSwaps.

However I am having trouble getting the array to play nice.

```
 OSAtomicCompareAndSwapPtrBarrier(void *__oldValue, void *__newValue, 
void *volatile *__theValue)
```

is the compare and swap function.

and inside my struct I have

```
 Ambigous * volatile* list;
```

and the call is

```
bool res=OSAtomicCompareAndSwapPtrBarrier(current_node, new_node, local->list[pos]);
```

When I try to cas by

```
bool res=OSAtomicCompareAndSwapPtrBarrier(current_node, new_node, (void * volatile *)local->list[pos]);
```

I get a bad EXE_BAD_ACCESS

So i guess what i am answering is how should i declare the array of volatile pointers?

Comment: `Ambiguous` is how you spell it. (But I don't know how to spell `cas`.)

Comment: I know, but the data structure is Ambigous, it was an inside joke when we made it. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you want

```
bool res = OSAtomicCompareAndSwapPtrBarrier(
              current_node, new_node, local->list + pos);
```

Note that the CAS operation is basically

```
bool CAS(void* old, void* new_, void* volatile* val) {
   /*atomic*/ {
     if (old == *val) {
         *val = new_;
         return true;
     } else
         return false;
   }
}
```

If you pass a `list[pos]`, the 3rd argument will be of type `Ambigous*`, and `*val` will be of type `struct Ambigous` which cannot be compared to a pointer.

Comment: When I try this i get the error: invalid conversion from 'HashTable<int, int>::Ambigous* volatile*' to 'void* volatile*'

Comment: Well, then you need to use `reinterpret_cast<void*volatile*>(local->list+pos)` as the last argument then.

Comment: K thanks! btw whats the difference between  reinterpret_cast<void*volatile*> and just (void*volatile*)?

Comment: @Steven: C style cast and C++ style cast. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332030/when-should-static-cast-dynamic-cast-and-reinterpret-cast-be-used

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem isn't a type issue - you've misunderstood the semantics of `OSAtomicCompareAndSwapPtrBarrier()`. You need to give `OSAtomicCompareAndSwapPtrBarrier` a pointer to the memory location holding the pointer you want to update. In this case, that's the location of `local->list[pos]` - this can be written either as `local->list + pos` or perhaps more readably `&(local->list[pos])`.

Since you're dealing with C++, not plain C, so you will need a cast:

```
bool res=OSAtomicCompareAndSwapPtrBarrier(current_node, new_node, (void*volatile*)&(local->list[pos]));
```